# How to terate through Record (Object) and return the array of Element(dom) in ONE LINE

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the object

```
type MyType = 'name' | 'base' | 'six';

obj: MyType = {
  'name': {key: 'm1'},
  'base': {key: 'm2'},
  'six': {key: 'm3'},
}
```

I want to iterate through obj and get the LIST of doms such as

```
<div>name,m1</div><div>base,m2</div><div>six,m3</div>
```

Somehow I want to reduce or maps to achieve this. I kindda failed but this is what I want.

```
Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {return <div>key,item[key]</div>};
```

Comment: `<div>key,item[key]</div>` -> `acc + "<div>" + key + "," + item[key] + "</div>"`?

Comment: Although `key` is also *not* a key but a key-value pair.

Comment: `obj: MyType` also cannot be correct because `MyType` is a union of string literals.

Comment: try ``Object.keys(MyType).map(k=>  `<div> ${k}, ${ MyType[k]['key'] } <div/>` )``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a padding for key/value.

```js
const
    pad = (array, tag) => array.map(v => `<${tag}>${v}</${tag}>`).join(''),
    object = { name: { key: 'm1' }, base: { key: 'm2' }, six: { key: 'm3' } },
    string = pad(Object.entries(object).map(([k, { key }]) => [k, key].join()), 'div');

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.keys(MyType).map(k=>  `<div> ${k}, ${ MyType[k]['key'] } <div/>` ).join("")
```

Output:

```
<div> name, m1 <div/><div> base, m2 <div/><div> six, m3 <div/>
```